# Failed to resolve 'minio' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")) in django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose, minio

Hello I'm trying to start Minio using docker, but i get this error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='minio', port=9000): Max retries exceeded with url: /local-static?location= (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd2de09e490>: Failed to resolve 'minio' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)"))
```

this happens when it checks if the bucket exists during start up here:

```
if self.auto_create_bucket and not self.client.bucket_exists(
```

it seems it doesn't recognize the host 'minio'

this is my docker-compose for with minio included:
this is my docker-compose for with minio included:
this is my docker-compose for with minio included:
this is my docker-compose for with minio included:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.7
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - PGUSER=backend
      - POSTGRES_USER=backend
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=backend
      - POSTGRES_DB=backend
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./packages/backend
      target: backend
    command: ["./scripts/runtime/run_local.sh"]
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    depends_on:
      stripemock:
        condition: service_started
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      broker:
        condition: service_started
      result:
        condition: service_started
      minio:
        condition: service_started
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  broker:
    image: "rabbitmq:alpine"

  result:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    env_file: 
      - packages/backend/.env
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  
  celery:
    build:
      context: ./packages/backend
      target: backend
    command: celery --app=my_project worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    env_file: 
      - packages/backend/.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - broker
      - result

  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    hostname: minio
    container_name: minio-storage
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    env_file:
      - packages/backend/.env
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data

  workers:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./packages/workers/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db

volumes:
  minio_data:
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you starting the Python application?  Is it in the same Compose file?  Can you [edit] the question to include this detail?

Comment: Did you try adding a custom network and using the custom network instead of the default one? https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/